# Applying an event listener to all instances on the stage of an item, and deleting the specific item

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have a list of items in a scrolling list, I would like the user to click on a specific item to delete it - I need to apply an eventListener to all instances of that item, so that whatever item is clicked, it is deleted

This is the first function:

```
private function dataLoaded(event:Event):void {
        // this holds the loaded xml data //
        data = new XML(event.target.data);
        //items properties call - add other calls to master properties later on//
        items = data.item;
        // parsing of each ingredient//
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
            // instantiation of mcItem (the stage for each item)
            _item = new Item();
            // sets //over// layer to invisible / transparent //
            _item.item_btn_over.alpha = 0;
            // creates the var itemTextField //
            _itemTextField = new TextField();
            // _itemTextField visual attributes //
            _itemTextField.x = _textFieldXPosition + _textFieldPaddingLeft;
            _itemTextField.y = _textFieldYPosition;
            _itemTextField.selectable = true;
            _itemTextField.wordWrap = true;
            _itemTextField.width = _textFieldWidth;
            _itemTextField.height = _textFieldHeight;
            _itemTextField.embedFonts = true;
            _defaultFormat.color = 0x111112;
            _defaultFormat.font = _arialRounded.fontName;
            _defaultFormat.size = 18;
            _itemTextField.defaultTextFormat = _defaultFormat;
            _itemTextField.text = items[i].toString();
            //adds textfield to displaylist//
            _item.addChild(_itemTextField);
            //vertical positioning//
            _item.y = i * _itemPosition;

            _item.buttonMode = true;
            _item.mouseChildren = false;
            //adds items to container displaylist//
            _container.addChild(_item);

        }

            // Input Mask//
            _mask = new Shape();
            _mask.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            _mask.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _maskWidth, _maskHeight);
            _mask.graphics.endFill();
            // Positioning of input mask//
            // horizontal centering of input mask//
            _mask.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _container.width / 2;
            _mask.y = _paddingTop;
            // adds the mask onto the stage//
            addChild(_mask);
            // assigns the above mask to the container //
            _container.mask = _mask;
            // Positioning of container with the mask//
            // horizontal centering of container //
            _container.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _container.width / 2;
            // vertical position of container //
            _container.y = _paddingTop;

            //Container background stylings//
            _background = new Shape();
            _background.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            _background.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _container.width, _container.height);
            _background.graphics.endFill();
            _container.addChildAt(_background, 0);
            //End of container background stylings//
            _item.parent.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked );
            _container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, movingOver);
            _container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, movingOut);
        }
```

And here is my `itemClicked` function:

```
function itemClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
                _item.parent.removeChild(_item);            
        }
```

Unfortunately, my previous efforts have only managed to delete the last item in the list. How do I apply a listener to all instances, but in the listener function only delete the item that has been clicked on?

Comment: You need to show us more code. Where you are setting up the event listeners for all the items. I have a feeling you are doing that incorrectly.

Comment: @prototypical I have posted the full function above (I can post my public variable declarations as well if you wish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have what I am assuming is a class member variable called _item, and as you loop through, you are reusing that variable to create your new item. So, _item is only ever a reference to the last item you created.

So when you use it in your itemClickHandler -- it ALWAYS references the last item you created.

Here's an example of what you should be doing :

```
// this is just example code for your dataLoaded function showing the correct concept
for (var i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) 
{
     var newItem:Item = new Item;
     // do whatever you need to newItem
     newItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICKED, itemClicked);
}

function itemClicked(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
     var curItem:Item = event.currentTarget as Item;
     curItem.parent.removeChild(curItem);            
}
```

Although you could do this as well :

```
// this is just example code for your dataLoaded function showing the correct concept
for (var i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) 
{
     var newItem:Item = new Item;
     // do whatever you need to newItem
}

_container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICKED, itemClicked);

function itemClicked(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
     // you could also have a check here to see if it is indeed an Item

     var curItem:Item = event.target as Item;
     curItem.parent.removeChild(curItem);            
}
```

This second approach has the advantage of only 1 listener, and therefore you'll only need to remove 1 when you are done with the list.

Comment: I applaud this solution but the solution below is simpler and doesn't require that I restructure my `dataLoaded` function at all. Thank you for your help though. In your mind would you suggest that your solution has any other perks over the solution below?

Comment: I added another alternative, that has the perk of only creating 1 listener as opposed to one per however many items you add.  The way you did it will work, but it's kind of sloppy in that you even fooled yourself into thinking that _item was something it wasn't. -- good practice does indeed have it's advantages. That is a perk imo :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the clicked item in the event listener as evt.target

Try:

```
function itemClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(evt.target is Item) {
        var item:Item = Item(evt.target);
        item.parent.removeChild(item);
    }
}
```